# ASP MVC Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, mime-types

I'm used to reference all my `css` and `js` file without bundling like this :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'/>
```

But since I use Bundling I get the following error message in chrome:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/javascript: "http://localhost:9432/Assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js".

I found that I should set `Content-Type` to  `application/javascript` but I don't how can I do this.

Whats your suggestion for resolve this problem?

**UPDATE:**

Here is my code:

```
          bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/AdminStyle").Include(
                  "~/Assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
                  "~/Assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css",
                  "~/Assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css",
                  "~/Assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch-rtl.min.css",
                  "~/Assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-select/css/bootstrap-select-rtl.css",
                  "~/Assets/global/css/components-rounded-rtl.min.css",
                  "~/Assets/global/css/plugins-rtl.min.css",
                  "~/Assets/layouts/layout3/css/layout-rtl.min.css",
                  "~/Assets/layouts/layout3/css/themes/default-rtl.min.css",
                  "~/Assets/layouts/layout3/css/custom.css",
                  "~/Assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-social-button/css/bootstrap-social.css",
                  "~/Assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-toastr/toastr.min.css",
                  "~/Assets/global/css/Custom.css",
                  "~/Assets/global/css/helper.css"));
```

And

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/AdminScript").Include(
      "~/Assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
      "~/Assets/global/plugins/js.cookie.min.js",
      "~/Assets/global/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
      "~/Assets/global/plugins/jquery.blockui.min.js",
      "~/Assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js",
      "~/Assets/global/scripts/app.min.js",
      "~/Assets/layouts/layout3/scripts/layout.min.js",
      "~/Assets/layouts/layout3/scripts/demo.min.js",
      "~/Assets/layouts/global/scripts/quick-sidebar.min.js",
      "~/Assets/layouts/global/scripts/quick-nav.min.js",
      "~/Assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"));
```

Comment: have you bundled your css and js together?

Comment: No "I didn't do this.

Comment: And how are you rendering them? Are you doing `@Styles.Render("~/bundles/AdminScript")` instead of `@Scripts.Render()` in your `cshtml`

Comment: Thanks, my problem is solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are rendering js file as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bundles/....">`

So, in your `cshtml`, change `@Styles.Render("~/bundles/AdminScript")` to `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/AdminScript")`

Answer (score 2):

In my case , my problem was that I used `ScriptBundle` while I should have used `StyleBundle`.

**Wrong code:**

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/rating").Include(
                "~/Content/fontawesome-stars.css"));
```

**Correct code:**

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/rating").Include(
                "~/Content/fontawesome-stars.css"));
```

You have to be careful with these bundles because it compiles perfectly and runs on local computer without problems but on production is where all the problems appear !

Comment: My problem was almost the exact opposite of the OP problem

Comment: Or in my case Bundle instead of StyleBundle.